# Version display on Right Click Open With on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

I have developed an app which supports opening of text files. Everything is working fine except when right clicking on .txt files and choosing `open with...` it displays my application with its version in brackets. TextEditor (1.0.0.0)

I want to display only Application name there. How can that be achieved so it is like how for .pdf files  Adobe Reader is displayed and not the version.

Comment: Do You have more than one ".app" file on Your disk? If so, system may show version in order to not confuse You which version is used to open this file. You can also rebuild LaunchServices

Comment: Is your app stand-alone or does it target the Mac App Store?

Comment: Its standalone app. No there is only one version of the app.